# Oracle - How can I find the session id of a shell script (Linux)?

Tags: oracle, linux, session

I have a Linux script run periodically from crontab which executes some sql scripts.  How can I get/identify the session of that running job?

thanks

Comment: are you looking for a way to find your current session (from within the script) or find the session of the running script from an other session?

Comment: i'm trying to find the session of the script from another session.  Say I have a running script and from SQLDeveloper i want to find that session to monitor it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like **ik_zelf** said, try to be more explicit.

If you need the session info, for the script that runs from crontab, then the query below will give you some details:

```
 SELECT 
    a.SID,
    a.USERNAME,
    a.STATUS,
    a.SERVER,
    a.SCHEMANAME,
    a.OSUSER,
    a.MACHINE,
    a.TERMINAL,
    a.PROGRAM,
    a.SQL_EXEC_START
FROM
    v$SESSION a
WHERE
    a.PROGRAM like 'sqlplus%'    
ORDER BY
    a.PROGRAM
```

I imagine that the the shell script is using sqlplus.

The output should look like:

```
1219    SYS ACTIVE  DEDICATED   SYS oracle11    instance_name       sqlplus@instance_name (TNS V1-V3)   8/8/2012 2:41:20 PM
774 SYS INACTIVE    DEDICATED   SYS oracle11    instance_name   pts/1   sqlplus@instance_name (TNS V1-V3)
```

Comment: yes, i use something like _sqlplus -s $dwh_connect @$path_sql/check_link_db.sql_ in the _.ksh_ so this should do the trick.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In order to find a specific session running a certain script, it is easiest if the scripts makes itself identifiable by using dbms_application_info and dbms_session. See [Morgans Library](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_applic_info.html) for details. Also see [track the parts of my application that are in use](http://www.morganslibrary.org/hci/hci005.html) for sample code.

Doing so enables you to select on v$session and filter not only on username and machine but also on module, action, client_info and client_id. Username and machine are not mutable but the other columns are controlled by dbms_application_info and dbms_session. Using those makes your script recognizable. This of course, only works when the other session has select privileges on v_$session.

dbms_application_info is also great for finding where your code is running; a way to instrumentate your code to make performance analysis easier.

your code in SQLdeveloper would be as simple as

```
select sid 
from gv$session
where module = 'what you specified'
order by sid
/
```

The code added in the script to make this work would be

```
exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('some detail'); 
exec dbms_application_info.set_module('what you specified','action'); 
exec dbms_session.set_identifier('DDD');
```

Comment: thanks, this is more helpful in the long run, a quicker method to identify scripts, but unfortunately this requires editing of scripts which are not mine.  thanks!